# Selenium element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What I am trying to do here is get this script to check a "I have read and agree to the terms and services" checkbox as shown in the photo the highlighted is the html for the checkbox itself. [image]

This is the code I am using in order to locate and click on the checkbox

```
tos_checkbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-checkbox-1-input']")
tos_checkbox.click()
```

When I run the script I get an error returned saying

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="mat-checkbox-1-input" class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Here is a copy of the full script so far if that is necessary info

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://onlinebusiness.icbc.com/webdeas-ui/login;type=driver')

lastname_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-0']")
licensenumber_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-1']")
keyword_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-2']")

lastname_input.send_keys("<lastname>")
licensenumber_input.send_keys("<licensenumber>")
keyword_input.send_keys("<keyword>")

tos_checkbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-checkbox-1-input']")
tos_checkbox.click()

login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='mat-raised-button']")
login_button.click()

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click on the **parent element** (with './..') and it'll work fine:

```
tos_checkbox = brower.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-checkbox-1-input']/./..")
tos_checkbox.click()
```

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mat-checkbox-1 > label > div"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    //Launch the application        
    driver.get("url here");

    //Find element by link text and store in variable "Element"             
    WebElement Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(" "));

    //This will scroll the page till the element is found       
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);
```